# SwiftUI NavigationLink: Expecting New View Instance on Each Navigation, But Created Only Once

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, state-management, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a SwiftUI app where a main screen displays a list of items. The user can either navigate to an existing item by tapping on it or create a new item by clicking a "+" icon. Each item has a UUID, and it's crucial that tapping the "+" icon always creates a new item instance, even if the user navigates back to the main screen without saving the new item.

This functionality is important due to specific requirements in my app (details omitted for brevity).

I've noticed that SwiftUI seems to only create the detail view instance once, even when navigating back and forth. I expect a new instance of the view (and the corresponding item) each time the "+" is tapped, but this isn't happening. Common solutions I've found feel more like workarounds than proper implementations for what seems like a basic pattern.

Is there a SwiftUI-centric approach to ensuring a new item and its associated view are created each time the "+" button is tapped?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dataRepository = DataRepository()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                List {
                    ForEach(dataRepository.items) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item, isAddScreen: false, dataRepository: dataRepository)) {
                            Text(item.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(memo: nil, isAddScreen: true, dataRepository: dataRepository)) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                })
                .navigationBarTitle("Items")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var item: Item?
    let isAddScreen: Bool
    let dataRepository: DataRepository

    init(item: Item?, isAddScreen: Bool, dataRepository: DataRepository) {
        print("this will print when the app launches") // <---------------------------- PROBLEM
        print("but not each subsequent time that we navigate here!")
        self.isAddScreen = isAddScreen
        self.dataRepository = dataRepository
        if isAddScreen {
            let newItem = Item(name: "New Item") // <---------------------------- PROBLEM
            self._item = State(initialValue: newItem)
        } else {
            self._item = State(initialValue: item!)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        // Detail view implementation...
    }
}

class DataRepository: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [/* initial items */]
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: Be careful with NavigationLink because the destination view is created when the link is displayed, not when the link is tapped. You can verify this by adding a print statement in the init of the destination view.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using some old tutorials but some basics...

`State` should always be `private` and should not come from a parent because there is an underlying storage that conflicts.

`State` is actually in charge of the "Identity" of the `View`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

See the comments below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectedList: View {
    @StateObject var dataRepository = DataRepository()
    //Controls navigation
    @State private var selection: Item.ID?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                List {
                    ForEach($dataRepository.items) { $item in
                        NavigationLink(item.name, tag: item.id, selection: $selection){
                            DetailView(item: $item, dataRepository: dataRepository)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    //Create the item
                    let new = Item.init(name: "New Item")
                    //Append it
                    dataRepository.items.append(new)
                    //Navigate
                    selection = new.id
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                    
                }))
                
                .navigationBarTitle("Items")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    //Two-way connection, State should never come from a parent it interferes with SwitUI's storage.
    @Binding var item: Item
    //Has the ability to observe the repository
    @ObservedObject var dataRepository: DataRepository
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $item.name)
    }
}

class DataRepository: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [/* initial items */]
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}
#Preview {
    SelectedList()
}
```

But like I mentioned this is a very old approach iOS 13-14 most of this is deprecated.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(content:)-5w0tj

The video below is very helpful in understanding SwiftUI.

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022